# how apply Theme in dynamically master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there override PreInit in Master Page? or Inheritance of PreInit Possible in MasterPage?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a base page class for all your pages you can apply following:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private string _theme = "Custom";
    public string Theme
    {
        get { return _theme; }
        set { _theme = value; }
    }
}

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object  sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var siteMaster = this.Master as SiteMaster;
        if (siteMaster != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteMaster.Theme))
        {
            Theme = siteMaster.Theme;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly apply an ASP.NET theme to a master page. If you add a theme attribute to the @ Master directive, the page will raise an error when it runs.

However, themes are applied to master pages under these circumstances:

If a theme is defined in the content page. Master pages are resolved in the context of content pages, so the content page's theme is applied to the master page as well.